Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> Intervention\Image\Interfaces\DriverInterface|string $driver ]] in class
I'm using :

Laravel 11
"mews/captcha": "^3.4"
Windows
Laragon

error occurs when i want to try {!! captcha_img() !!}
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> Intervention\Image\Interfaces\DriverInterface|string $driver ]] in class Intervention\Image\ImageManager

how to solve this error?

i use same config as @Arif hidayah
i just change the value in composer.json file
{
"mews/captcha": "3.3.3",
"intervention/image": "2.7.2",
}

Thank you sir, the problem is solved! Thanks :D

There might be a bug at the time I am writing this answer. I advise you to install version 3.3.3
Also, ensure that you have intervention/image: ~2.5 installed if you have explicitly included it in the composer.json otherwise a fresh installation of version 3.3.3 will solve the problem
